# XPath accessing a non-uniform XML file

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xpath

I have an XML file that's modeled something like the following:

```
<data>
    <customer>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <model>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <history>
                    <date></date>
                    <location></location>
                </history>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <history>
                    <date></date>
                    <location></location>
                </history>
            </item>
        </model>
        <model>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <history>
                    <date></date>
                    <location></location>
                </history>
            </item>
        </model>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <model>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <history>
                    <date></date>
                    <location></location>
                </history>
            </item>
            <item>
                <id></id>
                <history>
                    <date></date>
                    <location></location>
                </history>
            </item>
        </model>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
    </customer>
</data>
```

Using XPath in C#, I need to access the following for each customer:

```
customer/id
customer/name
customer/model/id
customer/model/name
customer/model/item/id
customer/model/item/history/date
customer/model/item/history/location
```

When data does not exist for any given customer, then the result stored will be null, since all fields of my customer object must be populated.  If the XML file was uniform, this would be easy.  My problem is accessing each customer's data when each customer may potentially have a different number of model and item nodes.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use XPath and not LinqToXml for example ?

Comment: @TommyGrovnes I've used LinqToXml in the past, but this project requires XPath.

Comment: You can get a `count()` of the number of `model` and/or `item` elements, and can select the set for a given XPath. Accessing them isn't a problem. You just need to decide what you want to do when there are none, one, or many of those things. If you could describe what you want to do, then you might get some answers to help you achieve it.

Comment: @MadsHansen XML1 is received daily.  My app needs to extract data from this file and use it to create XML2, which will processed later on.  To make XML2 easier to process, it will be normalized so that each record will be a transaction representing the data extracted from XML1 ordered by the date in XML1.  XML1 is not normalized and has an unequal number of nodes, so missing data will be represented as NULL in XML2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the result will consist of these types of object:

```
Customer, Model, Item and History
```

The pseudo - code for populating them is:

1. Select all `/data/customer` elements
2. For each of the nodes selected in 1. do:
3. Select `./id` and `./name` and populate the corresponding properties of the object.
4. Populate a `List<Model>` property from all `model` children of the current `customer` element:
5. Select all `./model` children of the current element.
6. For each selected `model` element in 5. create a Model object and populate its properties:
7. For the current Model object populate its Id and Name properties by selecting the `./id` and `./name` children of the current `model` element.
8. Populate a `List<Item>` property from all `item` children of the current `model` element:
9. Select all `./item` children of the current element.
10. For the current Item object populate its Id property by selecting the `./id` child of the current `item` element.
11. In a similar way populate the History property of the Item object with a History object, that you create and populate from the `./history` child of the current `item` element.

Of course, you can skip all this if you use XML Serialization -- read about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: The result would be an object containing `historyDate, customerID, customerName, modelID, modelName, itemID, historyLocation`.  I'm reading about Serialization right now.  It appears to replace XPath, but maybe it will work.

Comment: @meffordm, XML Serialization is probably the most convenient and *reusable* technology to use for such kind of tasks. The object you are working with is simpler than what I imagined and can be populated in a quite straightforward way: Just after step 1, evaluate an XPath expression for each of the properties, and if something is selected -- then populate, otherwise leave null or a default value (such as 0 for ints or string.Empty for strings.

Comment: So, Serialization is more reusable, meaning it would be better as a standard.  However, since my project is not that complex, XPath would still be acceptable, and in using XPath I should create an XPath expression for each node type that I want to store (`historyDate, customerID, customerName, modelID, modelName, itemID, historyLocation') and evaluate these with each customer.  Is that correct?

Comment: @meffordm, Correct. Even better, if it is guaranteed that all elements you want to select do exist, you may specify a single XPath expression that selects all properties for the object, and then access these from the returned XmlNodeList -- they are there in document order.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I can't guarantee all of the elements will always exits.  In fact, `customerID` and `customerName` are the only ones that must exist, while all others depend on customer requirements and inventories.  How would Serialization handle this case?

Comment: I think serialization will set the corresponding properties to null.